# Ubuntu 20.04.2 does not recognize 4k resolution on Samsung 28" 4K UE590 monitor

Tags: 20.04, hdmi, amd-graphics, samsung, 4k-monitor

Ubuntu 20.04.2 does not recognize 4k resolution on Samsung 28" 4K UE590 monitor.
The monitor has the HDMI1 and HDMI2 input, the HDMI1 input ubuntu works 4k but with only 30fps, standard, as the manufacturer itself informs that it is a maximum of 30fps. On HDMI2 the manufacturer says it's 60fps, but when I connect to the monitor on HDMI2 with a rx570 4gb, ubuntu does not recognize and only has a resolution of 720x480.

- Updated AMD drivers
- I configured it on xranr, without success

On Windows 4K works perfectly fine on HDMI2 which supports 60fps, but on ubuntu it doesn't work!!!

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 0):

I had a same problem with my LG 29 Inch widescreen monitor.
I had used the command line to add the new resolution to the display settings and then set that for my monitor display.
Use the below commands.

```
sudo xrandr --newmode <modeLine>
```

To get the modeline:

```
cvt 2560 1080 70
```

My display example command:

```
sudo xrandr --newmode "2560x1080_70.00"  272.25  2560 2736 3008 3456  1080 1083 1093 1127 -hsync +vsync
```

To add the resoution for your selected output for the display:

```
sudo xrandr --addmode <displayName> <modename(the text in quotes of the previous command output)>
```

To get the display name use the `xrandr` linux command output
my display example of adding a resolution:

```
sudo xrandr --addmode HDMI-1 2560x1080_70.00
```

Note: my resolution is 2560x1080 and the refresh rate is 70.
You can also put them to your .xprofile file.

Hope this helps you